# Zonal Statistics for Overlapping Zones Consistent failure

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, overlapping-features, zonal-statistics, error-001156

I am trying to run Zonal Statistics for Overlapping Zones on some Buffer feature classes that overlap. I downloaded and ran the script and it succeeded in calculating the zonal statistics for my first feature class and it took about 12 minutes. Since then, I have not gotten it to succeed, and it has taken over 2 hours to complete, and fails every time with Error 001156: cannot write OID FSP001 to table (FSP001 being the name of one of my buffers). It always has this error regardless of which feature class I input into the script. The raster is just a reclassed basemap. I would like to avoid doing each zone individually as there are over 500 of them. I've run this script about 10 times, and every time it has the same error, except for the first time when it succeeded, despite there being no discernible difference between the first feature class and the second one. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and it is highly discouraging.

Comment: Are you having it write the result to the same file as the first successful attempt?

Comment: No, I am having it write the results to different files.